# Why Openshift imagestream hash is different from Redhat registry API hash?

Tags: docker, hash, containers, openshift, redhat

I'm trying to develop an automation script to notify a certain team that some container images are outdated in a certain Openshift project inside an  Openshift cluster.

To do that one of the steps of the algorithm is comparing the current ImageStream hash:

`oc get is -n default registry-console -o json | jq '.status.tags[0].items[0].image' | awk -F: '{ print $2 }'`

then I tried to list all the tags with 3.9 in the registry and grep for the output of that first command above:

`curl -sL https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/repositories/openshift3/registry-console/tags | jq 'to_entries | select(.[].key | contains("v3.9"))' | grep $hash`

And I have no matches.

Then I tried creating a new ImageStream for testing, pointing to a specific Redhat registry tag and even so the image hash generated by Openshift is different from the Redhat Openshift official registry.

Why is this happening? Is it possible to compare container image hashes in Openshift to be sure they are the same?